# Executing IDatabaseInitializer

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first, ninject

I've implemented my own `Database Initializer` inherited from `DropDatabaseIfModelChanges<>()`

So:

`public class MyDatabaseInitializer : DropDatabaseIfModelChanges<MyDatabaseContext>()`

I use it in my `Global.asax` file and do:

```
protect void Application_Start()
{
    // some normal app start stuff

    Database.SetInitializer(new MyDatabaseInitializer());

    // create ninject kernel and then set DependencyResolver here
}
```

Now that just sets up an `Initializer` I actually want to execute the `void InitializeDatabase(TContext context);` where it then drops and creates the database.

It does do it when it gets to a line executing a database request such as:

`_repository.MyTable.ToList()`

Note, I'm using the repository pattern and ninject.

However I wish to execute this drop create on application start!

How do I that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so I nailed it.

My `IDatabaseInitializer` implementation looks like this:

```
public class MyDatabaseInitializer : DropDatabaseIfModelChanges<MyDatabaseContext>()
{
    public MyDatabaseInitializer() : base ()
    {
        var context = new MyDatabaseContext();

        Seed(context);

        base.InitializeDatabase(context);

        // any other things I need to do here with the database
    }

    public override Seed(UXContext context)
    {
        // do my seed data here
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't get it.. you are injecting this initializer somewhere instead of calling Database.SetInitializer?